# Efficient way to concatenate uncertain strings in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, string, concatenation

I want to concatenate some strings from variables if the variables are not nil.  If they are nil, I don't want to include them.  The following code works but is clunky and grows proportionately more complex with additional variables. Can anyone recommend a more elegant way to do this?

```
NSString *city = self.address.city== nil ? @"" : self.address.city;
NSString *state = self.address.state== nil ? @"" : self.address.state;
NSString *zip = self.address.zip== nil ? @"" : self.address.zip;
NSString *bestCity;

if (city.length>0&&state.length>0&&zip.length>0) {
     bestCity = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@ %@", city, state,zip];
}
else if (city.length>0&&state.length>0) {
    bestName = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", city,state];
}
else if (city.length>0&&zip.length>0) {
    bestCity = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", city,zip];
}
else if (city.length>0&&zip.length>0) {
    bestCity = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", city,zip];
}
else if (city.length>0) {
    bestCity = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", city];
}
else if (state.length>0) {
    bestCity = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", state];
}
else if (zip.length>0) {
    bestCity = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", zip];
}
else {
    bestCity = @"";
}
```

Comment: Add the non-`nil` ones into an `NSMutableArray`, then [join them with a space](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/componentsJoinedByString:).

Comment: By the way, your `city,zip` case is repeated and `state,zip` case is missing.

Comment: You could also post this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, as it more of a code review question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do something like:

```
NSMutableArray *bestCityArr = [@[] mutableCopy]; // [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if (city.length > 0)
    [bestCityArr addObject:city];

if (state.length > 0)
    [bestCityArr addObject:state];

if (zip.length > 0)
    [bestCityArr addObject:zip];

NSString *bestCity = [bestCityArr componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

Comment: Hehe, looks like there's some consensus on the best approach :)

Comment: @hatfinch, you bet there is! ;)

Comment: This approach is better because it doesn't add empty strings.

Comment: Thank you Oyeoj and also hat finch!

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if (self.address.city)
    [items appendObject:self.address.city];
if (self.address.state)
    [items appendObject:self.address.state];
if (self.address.zip)
    [items appendObject:self.address.zip];

NSString *bestCity = [items componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

Comment: wow! did we just posted the same thing at the same time? I'm looking at the time interval `answered x xxx ago`, and yeah we just did.. cool!

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you!

```
- (NSString *)concatenateString
{
    NSMutableString *bestCity = [NSMutableString string];
    NSString *city = self.address.city ?: @"";
    [bestCity appendString:city];

    NSString *state = self.address.state ?: @"";
    if (state.length > 0) {
        [bestCity appendString:@" "];
    }

    [bestCity appendString:state]];

    NSString *zip = self.address.zip ?: @"";
    if (zip.length > 0) {
        [bestCity appendString:@" "];
    }

    [bestCity appendString:zip];

    return bestCity.length > 0 ? bestCity : @"";
}
```

Comment: What's the point of using `stringWithFormat:`? 1) It's not needed at all. 2) If it was, why not use `appendFormat:`?

Comment: @rmaddy, thanks for your reminder. I'm carelessness!